Open Problem on $Aut(\mathcal{P}(\omega)/fin$
In Jan van mills "Problems on $\beta \mathbb{N}$" in question 4 they ask:
"Can one have non-trivial autohomeomorphisms but only very
mild ones; the set of points where an autohomeomorphism is truly non-trivial is always finite?"
Is there any connection between near coherence classes of ultrafilters and this question(Working in CH)? Can we apply results on the consistency of there being, e.g. $2^{\mathfrak{c}}$ near coherence classes, to get a negative answer to our question? For any given nontrivial automorphism, then use P-points and near coherence classes to show that the set needs to have cardinality $2^{\mathfrak{c}}$.
Can anyone confirm if it is possible that these concepts have a connection? Or am i completely off the tracks here?
